# Docker Java number of available CPU cores

Tags: java, docker

What's a safe way to get the number of CPU cores that a docker instance is able to use?

I know it's this in plain Java (which ill include the logical cores also):

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Is this also ok when the Java app is run inside a docker image, or should I make additional considerations?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your Java version.  Older versions of Java would give you the number of cores on the docker server, whereas what you probably want is the number available to the container.  From 8u131 and Java 9, [this is fixed](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits).

Comment: This is the correct answer and can be easily tested using jshell. Just drop into a dockerized `JShell` with and without `--cpus 1` and run `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();`. From the command line: `docker run -it --rm --cpus 1 openjdk:11-jdk`

Comment: docker run -it --rm --cpus 2.5 openjdk:17 bash -c 'echo "Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()" | jshell'

Answer (score 1):

On linux hosts you can read the pseudo files present in the path /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker pseudo file system which keeps track of the cpu usage.
In above path look for the directory named as the full container ID of the container you want to check and move into that directory.
Then read the file named cpuacct.usage_percpu and you can see all the cpu time the container is consuming per each core.
Absolute path for the above file will be like this `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker/f24b61ce690fe77f9eb0f029215e9491cc54642d686770d71218b4a0ada27ce3`
In java you can just read these pseudo files and do the computations for per cpu core usage.