# Vertx in Kubernetes only work with two cpu

Tags: java, kubernetes, vert.x

I'm facing a very weird behavior, trying to scale up vertically, running multiple Verticles

When I deploy in my local machine I can see the multiple Verticles and event-loop threads are created

```
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.533 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.534 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.534 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.535 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.535 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.536 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-7] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:10.536 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-7] INFO  Async-flow-http-proxy running......
```

Then when I run some queries I can see that all event-loops are used in round-robin fashion.

```
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.126 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.127 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.127 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-6] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.126 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
```

But, when I deploy in `Kubernetes`, and run the container with `Java 11`, and `cpu '10'`. I can still see that the multiple event-loops are created, but when I run request, only `two` of them are working, so then with big traffic I start struggling with only two event-loops

```
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.126 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
[] | 2022-06-01 13:29:11.127 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] INFO  AsyncFlowHttpProxy - Calling next service localhost on port 8091
```

Comment: Can you make sure the container creates the desired number of event loops? That would help understand if the problem is with environment detection or number of connections opened by the proxy

Comment: The event-loops are created as I can see in the logs that I share. What else can I check?

Comment: You could run a jshell command in your container to check how many cores are seen by the JVM (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833215/docker-java-number-of-available-cpu-cores#comment118874773_53223113)

Comment: I'm facing the same kind of issue. I have no problem running my vert.x application locally and I can see it running with up to 20 threads, but in k8s (k3s specifically) it's only using 2 threads, even though it should have more than enough resources to use more